# Healthcare delivery SQL

Tags: sql

I'm having an issue with a practice assessment regarding a health dataset. I have been tasked with counting the total number of emergency room visits for individuals diagnosed with schizophrenia with the conditions that anyone with icd10_category = f20 needs to have all of the records recorded. I was originally thinking that I should use an IF else statement because I come from a back end mindset however, I've never done anything like this in sql and I'm having a hard time finding documentation for this issue. Below I have a mockup of the code I had theorized but I don't know if this will work. Can someone please help? This is also my first time posting so any guidance or constructive criticism is better than heavy judgements :)

```
begin

declare @newId varchar
declare @sum int


select * from dbo.['Test dataset - SQL - Sep# 2021 $']


/*

If icd10_category == 'f20'
id=newId;
+=newId;


else
return;


return sum(newId);
*/
```

Comment: This question is a strong indication that you need to find a basic SQL book or tutorial. What you're asking to do should be something that is covered in the first chapter or two of that tutorial or book.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general issue to solve is this: you're imagining code written in a procedural style, then trying to squeeze it into a SQL-shaped box.

Specifically, you're trying to set variables and issue a series of instructions to get the thing you want.

This doesn't work as well as you might think, because SQL is a *declarative* language - you tell the database engine what you want it to give you and leave it to figure out the details (as opposed to giving it a set of instructions which it follows blindly, which is the procedural approach).

For this reason it *will* be hard to find documentation. Ultimately this will just take practice with SQL - learning a different approach to things and figuring out when to apply it. It's quite a nice way of doing things, once you get into the groove. But for now let's solve the concrete problem:

```sql
  SELECT patient_id, COUNT(*) AS n_visits
    FROM your_database.emergency_room_visits
   WHERE icd10_category = 'f20'
GROUP BY patient_id
```

Now, I lack your domain knowledge, so here I have imagined that `emergency_room_visits` is a table that looks like this:

```
patient_id | icd10_category |   date     | lots | of | other | stuff
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     1             'f19'      2022-01-01   ...
     2             'f20'      2022-01-01   ...
     2             'f20'      2022-02-14   ...
     3             'f20'      2022-02-15   ...
```

It will be up to you to look at the real table, but I imagine that:

- each record (row) corresponds to a patient visiting the emergency room
- each patient will have a unique ID (I called it `patient_id`)
- each patient will have something called `icd10_category` (I imagine there are a few values this can take, but only `'f20'` indicates the condition of interest)

If we have all of these then the query I outlined above will return

```
patient_id | n_visits
---------------------
     2          2
     3          1
```

Now, let's try to understand the query:

```sql
  SELECT patient_id, COUNT(*) AS n_visits
    FROM your_database.emergency_room_visits
   WHERE icd10_category = 'f20'
GROUP BY patient_id
```

Breaking it down:

- ignore the `SELECT` to start with
- the data are coming `FROM` the table of interest
- we only care about records for patients with this condition, so only retrieve data `WHERE icd10_category = 'f20'`
- we want to return the number of records *per patient*, so we must `GROUP BY patient_id`

Now, returning to `SELECT`:

- we ask for `patient_id` (the thing we grouped by) and
- `COUNT(*)` - a shorthand for "the number of records (rows) associated with each `patient_id`" - which we rename to `n_visits`, because that's the interpretation of this number.

(`COUNT` is an example of an aggregation function that reduces many records/rows down to one result)

Hopefully you can see what I mean by this being a 'declarative' style. We told the database engine what we wanted. It then grabs the table you mentioned, does some processing on it, and returns a *results table* in the format you requested.